# <Web2py> : List | Create | Modify and Delete Users directly from Python controller without using HMI

Tags: python, database, web2py

I have read a lot of cases and uses cases about web2py users.....
But my case is différent ;
I would like to

List,Create, Modify and Delete Users directly from Python controllers without using HMI

My user db (storage.sqlite) is always the same

```
login 0 is user0
login 1 is user1
```

and I can have a lot of users but user0 and user1 are always here

I would like to

1. List all users by id and username without user0 and user1 in a single ligne

   ```
   try :
       listusers = db(db.auth.............
       if len(listusers) == 0:
   except Exception as e:
       listusers = []
   ```
2. Create a user with a mail / login and Password directly using python method in the controller with the db (without the GUI)
3. Modify a password of an already created user directly using python method in the controller with the db (without the gui)
   Note : I have already the id and/or the username of the user
4. Delete an already created user directly using python method  in the controller with the db (without the gui)

> Note : I have already the id and/or the username of the user

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm really sorry... that's not the reason I have post this message... but no one have the solution so I try on stack overflow

Comment: You may specify a specific problem on what you have done, your post is just the detail of building a whole thing

Comment: No problem I have found the solution ....